# What is the benefit of using CqlTemplate vs CassandraTemplate?

Tags: cql, spring-data-cassandra

I would like to know what the benefits are using CqlTemplate vs CassandraTemplate? I am aware that CassandraTemplate allows for object mapping. But is there anything more? How do they handle batching? Is one more performant than the other?

Thank you